# Algorithm for Ruby's flatten() method implemented in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, object

I was reading a Ruby book and came across a function .flatten. So as the name suggest, it flattens an array like below:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]           #=> [1, 2, 3]
b = [ 4, 5, 6, [7, 8] ]   #=> [4, 5, 6, [7, 8]]
c = [ a, b, 9, 10 ]       #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, [7, 8]], 9, 10]
c.flatten                 #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

My question is I am trying to implement see if I can come up with an algorithm to in Java such that when passed an array(which might contain) other arrays, it'll return an array. I don't know perhaps there's a simpler way to do this or there might be an implementation of it already in Java. Regardless, I know I haven't waited my time giving it a shot today :)

Here is my algo to begin with:
    Create an arrayList.

```
 for each element in array as x, 
   if x element, add to arrayList
else
  do a recurse(pass x as arg)

  Once done, create a int array with size = arrayList.
  Loop arrayList and add each element
```

Here's my code so far:

```
public class Flatten {

public static void main(String[] args){
   a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]          
   b = [ 4, 5, 6, [7, 8] ] 
   c = [ a, b, 9, 10 ]       
   flatten(c);                 
}

public static int[] flatten(int[] a){
    ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i=0; i<a.; i
      Object o = a[i];  
        if(!obj instanceof Object[])){
          arr.add(a[i]);
   }

   else {
     int[] newArray = nR
      flatten(nR);
        }
     }     
  }

  int[] results = new int[ar.size()];

  for(int i=0; i<ar.size(); i++){
     int x = ar.get(i);
     int[i] = x;
  }

     return results;
  }
```

}

The tricky part of this algo is checking if an element is an array. Also is the problem that arrays in Java should be declared with their size.

Comment: You can't put an array in an `int[]`, it takes only integers.

Comment: In general, Java type system does not allow heterogeneous arrays. That's why such method doesn't make much sense in Java: there is nothing to flatten.

Comment: You could create a List<Object>, and store there anything (int and arrays alike), but I would strongly discourage you to do so because unlike ruby, java has type checks and everything works better if you use them properly. So it all depends on what is the thing your are modeling, but you should probably create a class hierarchy to handle that (in which the nodes could be arrays or ints).

Comment: Groovy does have heterogeneous lists, and it has `flatten` built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a method that will flatten many kinds of `Object` into a `List<Integer>` no matter how deeply nested. The method below will work for `int[]`, `int[][]`, `Integer`, `Integer[]`, `Integer[][]`,  `List<Integer>`, `List<List<Integer>>`, `List<int[]>` etc. (You could easily make it return an `int[]` instead).

```
public static List<Integer> flatten(Object object) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    helper(object, list);
    return list;
}

private static void helper(Object object, List<Integer> list) {
    if (object instanceof Integer) {
        list.add((Integer) object);
    } else if (object instanceof int[]) {
        for (int a : (int[]) object)
            list.add(a);
    } else if (object instanceof Object[]) {
        for (Object obj : (Object[]) object)
            helper(obj, list);
    } else if (object instanceof Iterable) {
        for (Object obj : (Iterable) object)
            helper(obj, list);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

However, this kind of thing is a **really terrible idea**. If you find yourself writing a load of `instanceof` checks, and then doing different things based on the result, you've most likely made some poor design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to implement an `Iterator flatten(Object ... items)` - returning an array of the correct size would involve walking all entries twice (once to count and once to fill). An `Iterator` could make use of a `stack` and flatten all `Iterable`s however deeply they are nested. That way all arrays and all `Collection`s would also flatten naturally. Besides, arrays are so 2014!!

This seems to work. It makes use of apache collections.IteratorUtils to create an Iterator over primitive arrays.

```
private static class FlatteningIterator implements Iterator {

    // All fall to null at end.
    Object o;
    // It is an iterator.
    Deque<Iterator> stack = new LinkedList();
    // The next object to deliver.
    Object next;

    private FlatteningIterator(Object o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        // Keep looking until found one or exhausted
        while (next == null && (!stack.isEmpty() || o != null)) {
            if (o != null) {
                // Check o first.
                if (o instanceof Iterator) {
                    // Any kind of iterator?
                    stack.push((Iterator) o);
                } else if (o instanceof Iterable) {
                    // Any Iterable.
                    stack.push(((Iterable) o).iterator());
                } else if (o.getClass().isArray()) {
                    // Primitive array! Use apache IteratorUtils
                    stack.push(IteratorUtils.arrayIterator(o));
                } else {
                    // Just return the object.
                    next = o;
                }
                o = null;
            }

            // Still not found one?
            if (next == null) {
                // Get it from the current iterator?
                Iterator it = stack.peek();
                if (it != null) {
                    if (it.hasNext()) {
                        // Walk it.
                        o = it.next();
                    } else {
                        // Exhausted the iterator.
                        stack.remove();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        Object n = hasNext() ? next : null;
        next = null;
        return n;
    }

}

public static Iterator<Object> flatten(Object o) {
    return new FlatteningIterator(o);
}

public void test() {
    List<Object> test = new ArrayList<>();
    test.add("Hello");
    test.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, new int[]{3, 6, 9, 12}, 4, 5));
    test.add("Bye");
    Iterator f = flatten(test);
    for (Object o : Iterables.in(f)) {
        System.out.print(o);
        if (f.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(",");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike ruby, java is a statically typed language. This means that you can't really have arrays in it, that contain both ints, and arrays as elements (well, you *can* ... but you should not).

So, flatten in java would look something like this (I do it with lists, because it is a bit easier for the sake of example, but it is the same idea):

```
public static List<String>  flatten(List<List<String>> list) {
   List<String> result = new LinkedList<~>();
   for(List<String> l: list) result.addAll(l);
   return result;
}
```